# UWP inner shadow with LinearGradientBrush

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

is there any way to make such an effect with `LinearGradientBrush`?
[image]

I also checked this question: [C# UWP Toolkit DropShadowPanel inner shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394895/c-sharp-uwp-toolkit-dropshadowpanel-inner-shadow)

In answer, they were using `DropShadowPanel` with `Rectangle`, that has `StrokeThickness="10"`. But this creates grey color border. I'm wondering is there any way to achieve it either with LinearGradientBrush or without StrokeThickness set to 10?

I would like to keep the original size of the grid and do not cut it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a border, you can truncate the border by adjusting `Grid.Clip`

```xml
<Grid Width="400"
      Height="200"
      Margin="24">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="20,20,360,160" />
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundColor"
       Fill="LightSteelBlue" />
    <controls:DropShadowPanel x:Name="InnerShadow"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                      BlurRadius="40"
                      ShadowOpacity="1"
                      Color="Black">
        <Rectangle x:Name="BorderColor"
           Stroke="LightGray"
           StrokeThickness="20" />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the code I adjusted the `DropShadowPanel` parameters to make the shadows more visible.

[image: Imgur]

But `LinearGradientBrush` may not be able to do this, because it is a linear gradient. For example, you can generate a gradient color from left to right from blue to black, but you cannot fade from the around to the center. If you have this need, you can try [RadialGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/brushes/radialgradientbrush) in WindowsCommunityToolkit.

Best regards.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, that I can cut off. But what if I just don't want any borders? I mean in your example there is no grey part, but there is a transparent part now(and I can see image under Grid). Is there any way to keep the original size of the parent Grid?

Comment: The screenshot does not indicate a transparent border, but just to make the shadows more visible. In fact, after capturing through `Grid.Clip`, it will only show the size of 340x140. You can choose to create a `UserControl`, then expose the `Width` and `Height` properties, and filter out this part of the border width by calculation internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DropShadowPanel as in the other answer and change the inner rectangle stroke to be white (or whatever your page background is).

```
<Grid Width="400" Height="200">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,400,200" />
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <controls:DropShadowPanel HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              BlurRadius="50"
                              ShadowOpacity="1"
                              Color="Black">
        <Rectangle Stroke="White"
                   StrokeThickness="10" />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
</Grid>
```

This creates the following:

[image]